# Is this valid json. I cant find where is the culprit?

Tags: json

Invalid JSON Data

```
{"broadcastId":"107040605846","channelId":"3EC40265-8F54-40AA-8576-D92DC0CEA080","channelName":"RTL","startDateTime":"2013-04-08 19:05:00","endDateTime":"2013-04-08 19:40:00","genre":"Serie","ageRating":"0","lengthPlain":"0","voteHumor":"0","voteAnspruch":"0","voteAction":"0","voteSpannung":"0","voteErotic":"0","country":null,"year":"0","title":"Alles was z\u00e4hlt","subtitle":"Folge 1658","description":"(1658)
Simones Widerstand gegen\u00fcber David br\u00f6ckelt. Als sich die beiden erneut k\u00fcssen, werden sie dabei prompt beobachtet... Hart f\u00fcr Ingo: Er hat seine Chance bei Bea gehabt und sie verpasst.","artists":null,"picLink":null,"isTip":"0"}
```

Comment: That's valid, you can test on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: What's your **actual** problem? Does some API decline processing that? Any error messages?

Comment: @Dev Actually, according to jsonlint, it's invalid. It's missing the closing curly brace.

Comment: check now. I edited json.

Comment: When I remove the space between "(1658)" and "Simones Widerstand" then i becomes valid json. Is it the space who causing the problem?